# Replace escaped single quotes with normal single quotes before and after a certain part of string [Java/Groovy]

Tags: java, regex, string, groovy

How to efficiently replace escaped single quotes with normal single quotes before and after the "current" outermost loop. In my case single quotes are escaped like this : `''`
The following  input string :

```
"set x = ''value''; //BEFORE
 Select 
''L1: LOOP
    set y = ''value2''
    SELECT ''L2: LOOP...END LOOP L2;'';
END LOOP L1;''; //Cur OuterMost LOOP
 if x = ''value'' then SELECT ''LEAVE L1''; //AFTER"
```

I want this Output. As you see, the body inside the outmost loop string is not being replaced i.e (`''` -> `'`)

```
"set x = 'value'; //BEFORE
Select 
'L1: LOOP
    set y = ''value2''
    SELECT ''L2: LOOP...END LOOP L2;'';
END LOOP L1;'; //Cur OuterMost LOOP
if x = 'value' then SELECT 'LEAVE L1'; //AFTER"
```

I wrote the following code. It's doing the job but still, can I make it shorter and efficient?

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?i)\\bLOOP\\b")
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(body)
if (matcher.find()) {
  int start = matcher.start()
  int end = StringUtils.lastIndexOf(body, "END LOOP")
  String beforeLoop = body[0..start - 1].replaceAll("''", "'")
  String afterLoop = body[end + 8..-1].replaceAll("''", "'")
  return beforeLoop + body[start..end + 7] + afterLoop
}
  return body.replaceAll("''", "'")
```

Comment: Right now, it looks as if `.replace("''", "'")` will do. Can you clarify?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I clarified with modifying the example

Comment: Can we assume that the loop ends on a newline? Is `(?sm)\bLOOP\b.*?^END LOOP\b` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/vmX0Se/1)) a valid regex for your cases?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes, the loop ends on new line i.e `...END LOOP L1;'';\n` . If that's what you mean.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  regex is un-escaping the inner single quotes as well, which I do not want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Assuming your outer loop ends with the leftmost `END LOOP` at the start of a line*, you can use a regex that matches the outer loops and matches and captures double `'` chars so that you could "unescape" the value in Group 1 when it matches. The regex is

```
/(?sm)\bLOOP\b.*?^END LOOP\b|('')/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/V9Ghi5/2). Details:

- `(?sm)` - dot matches line breaks (`s`) and `^` now matches start of a line (`m`)
- `\bLOOP\b` - whole word `LOOP`
- `.*?`  - any zero or more chars as few as possible
- `^` - start of a line
- `END LOOP\b` - whole word `END LOOP`
- `|` - or
- `('')` - Group 1: `''`

```
String body = "set x = ''value''; //BEFORE\n Select \n''L1: LOOP\n    set y = ''value2''\n    SELECT ''L2: LOOP...END LOOP L2;'';\nEND LOOP L1;''; //Cur OuterMost LOOP\n if x = ''value'' then SELECT ''LEAVE L1''; //AFTER"
body = body.replaceAll(/(?sm)\bLOOP\b.*?^END LOOP\b|('')/) { x,y ->
      y != null ? "'" : x
}
print(body)
```

See the [Groovy demo](https://ideone.com/uodyFI), output:

```
set x = 'value'; //BEFORE
 Select 
'L1: LOOP
    set y = ''value2''
    SELECT ''L2: LOOP...END LOOP L2;'';
END LOOP L1;'; //Cur OuterMost LOOP
 if x = 'value' then SELECT 'LEAVE L1'; //AFTER
```

Comment: can you explain me the closure you used with `{ x,y ->y != null ? "'" : x}` . I'm unable to understand this.

Comment: what are `x` and 'y' ? and what does `y != null ?  "'" : x` mean ?

Comment: @AbhishekDasgupta The `/(?sm)\bLOOP\b.*?^END LOOP\b|('')/` regex contains a single capturing group, `('')`, so `x` stands for the whole match value and `y` stands for the Group 1 value, i.e. `''`. If Group 1 is not matched, the value of `y` is `null` and we replace the match with the whole match value, else, we replace `''` with a single occurrence of a `'`.